# How to increment date and output the following date correctly using structures in C

Tags: c

I was practicing C language and found some exercise on the Web, so I had to write a code which can:

(1) Judge whether the year is a leap or not

(2) Perhaps, the date itself must be defined in the code

(3) In the last, based on the given date and function `IsLeapYear`, the program should output the date of the following day correctly (change the year/month if needed): Input: *2020-12-31*  Output: *2021-01-01* (**NOT** 2020-12-32)

I got stuck on the 3rd point, my code does not change the year/month, here my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct Date
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

typedef struct Date Date;

const int days[2][12] = {{31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}//common year
                        ,{31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}};//leap year


int isLeapYear(int year)//year is leap or common
{
    if(year%4==0&&year %100!=0 || year %400==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void increment(Date * p)
{
    p->day++;
    int leap=isLeapYear(p->year);

}

int main()
{
    //p->year = 2021,p->month = 2,p->day = 28
    Date today = {2021,12,31}; //2020 % 4 == 0 &&  2020 % 100 != 0
    printf("%d-%02d-%02d\n", today.year, today.month, today.day);

    increment(&today);//2021-03-01 NOT 2021-02-29
    printf("%d-%02d-%02d\n", today.year, today.month, today.day);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You *cannot* increment a date by simply incrementing the day. Convert to julian date before doing your operation and the convert back to year/month/day (Gregorian date). See [Julian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).

Comment: Well, you haven't started your exercise even, so what is the question? Start working! SO is not a homework writing service, even though we're generally willing to help people when they have actual problems, but only after demonstrating an effort on their side.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I gave u my draft, I have a problem with one Function. After all that how can u judge that I didn't even start.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check if an update to the year / month is required.
I suggest using this method to check

```
void increment(Date * p) {
    p->day++;
    int leap=isLeapYear(p->year);
    if (days[leap][p->month - 1] < p->day) {
        p->day = 1;
        p->month++;
    }
    if (p->month > 12) {
        p->month = 1;
        p->year++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not take into account the fact that in February (depending on which year is high or not) 28/29 days

Comment: You're right. It should be ```p->month - 1``` , and then each actual month number is the right index of the ```days``` array. I edited the answer and it should work now

Answer (score 0):

You have all the basic elements, you just need to check for the rollover on the days based on your "days" array. Rollover will also need to be checked for months

```
void incrementMonth(Date * p){
    p->month++;
    if (p->month > 12){
        p->month = 1;
        p->year++;
    }
}

void incrementDay(Date * p){
    int leap=isLeapYear(p->year);
    p->day++;
    if (p->day > days[leap][p->month-1]){
        p->day = 1;
        incrementMonth(p);
    }
}
```